# react web cam not releasing after checking cam and mic of the device

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]
Hi Team, I'm using **react-webcam,react-mic** in my project. In **first component** I'm using these 2 modules. these are working fine. So after checking cam, and mic functionality, I'm using **props.history.push()** to go to 2nd screen. In that screen I'm getting above recording screen. Can any one suggest how to release cam/mic when required in 2nd component.

To stop accessing cam & mic in the 2nd component I used **window.location.reload()**.So when page is reloading cam and mic are released. This is working fine in desktop, android devices. But in the iphone devices app is getting logout due to **window.location.reload()**.   Any suggestions please, thank in advance

Comment: From what I understand, you should `history.replace` the permission check screen with the 2nd screen instead of `push`. Note: I haven't use the mentioned libraries.

Comment: please share your code base also for better understanding

Comment: sure I'll update code files also in few minutes